Help Identify ebike electrical C13-like socket
What's the name of type of this socket?

I got this socket for my ebike, which is like C13 in dimension with different pins layout.
I want to upgrade my charger, most of them came with C13/C15, and replace that with this socket, but I can't seem to find them in Google, and Google image identifies them as a C13 .
Also the socket or port has no further info.
I don't want to change the charging port (it's a hassle to change, need to take out body parts, etc...), but will do this if I can't find the parts.
Does anybody know? Any help is appreciated.

All I have found is that they sell under "New energy 2+2 electric vehicle charging male connector" on a Chinese-only Alibaba website 1688.com. Here is the link to it: https://detail.1688.com/offer/803055573972.html   It seems to be a non-standard connector. Probably better to use a more common, easily found connector.

Calling @DavideAndrea

Yeah I have decided to swap it with a more common ones I can find for easier maintenance

My Identicon utility identifies that as a  Yueqing Weinuoer XGB-2+2.

{Source: Yueqing Weinuoer}
EDIT: After some OCR and translation work from Chinese, I find that the Chinese government specified this connector for "Lead-acid battery charger output plug form" in GB 42296-2022 that is generically called "the new national standard". (Chinese)
Please note that the standard receptacle has 2 signal sockets, while yours has 2 signal pins. Yours uses the reversed polarity, which is also available from that company.

Hope you don't mind, I've changed the image to a different one from the same source page which doesn't show a mirror image of the plug to avoid confusion. This matches the OPs connector exactly.

@Tom Carpenter. Of course I don't mind. I didn't see that 4th image because I didn't scroll to the right enough. Thank you for pointing it out to me.
